# MacBook Pro cannot extend displays

Tags: macbook-pro, display, dock, dual-screen, mirroring

I am using a 2019 13-inch MacBook Pro (2 Thunderbolt ports) with a dual monitor setup. I typically close my MacBook lid so the 2 monitors are my main monitors. However, with the lid closed. My MacBook only sees 1 monitor; both monitors show the exact same screen (so they mirror).

I've read online that typically this is caused by your dock. But I have no clue which dock to use if that's the case since my current dock: Club-3D USB Type C 3.2 Gen1 Triple Display Dynamic PD Charging Dock.

It works fine with a Windows laptop, connecting both screens and extending them.

I'm hoping since the exact same setup **does** work on Windows that there's a software fix.

If not, I'm curious to find out which dock to use that **does** also supports Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The specifications [here](https://www.club-3d.com/en/quick-view/2474/) state that this dock is an MST device.  Only SST is supported by macOS.  This is a current limitation of macOS.

You need a Thunderbolt dock.

Comment: Thanks Marc, that helps a lot. I was unaware of that. I will look up the difference between SST and MST and get myself a SST Dock. :)